# D3: Microlibraries for creating curves

Tags: javascript, d3.js

According to the D3 GitHub page, micro-libraries are available.
I was looking for the correct libraries to draw curves and thought that I found it ("d3-shape": https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#curves) but Unfortunately, I could not make it run without the "full" D3 library added to my project.

Am I doing something wrong? Can I make it somehow run without the complete D3 library but instead with micro-libraries?

Here is my CodePen; once you remove the full D3 library (and only keep the micro-libraries) it stops working: https://codepen.io/clmsvie/pen/OaLErV

```js
var lineGenerator = d3.line()
 .curve(d3.curveBundle.beta(1));

var points = [
 [0, 80],
 [100, 100],
 [200, 30],
 [300, 50],
 [400, 40],
 [500, 80]
];

var pathData = lineGenerator(points);

d3.select('path')
 .attr('d', pathData);

// Also draw points for reference
d3.select('svg')
 .selectAll('circle')
 .data(points)
 .enter()
 .append('circle')
 .attr('cx', function(d) {
  return d[0];
 })
 .attr('cy', function(d) {
  return d[1];
 })
 .attr('r', 3);
```

```css
path {
 fill: none;
 stroke: #999;
}
circle {
 fill: none;
 stroke: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-path.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-shape.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.2/d3.min.js"></script>


<svg width="700" height="110">
   <path></path>
</svg>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the following instead of the full d3

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-selection.v1.min.js"></script>
```

```js
var lineGenerator = d3.line()
 .curve(d3.curveBundle.beta(1));

var points = [
 [0, 80],
 [100, 100],
 [200, 30],
 [300, 50],
 [400, 40],
 [500, 80]
];

var pathData = lineGenerator(points);

d3.select('path')
 .attr('d', pathData);

// Also draw points for reference
d3.select('svg')
 .selectAll('circle')
 .data(points)
 .enter()
 .append('circle')
 .attr('cx', function(d) {
  return d[0];
 })
 .attr('cy', function(d) {
  return d[1];
 })
 .attr('r', 3);
```

```css
path {
 fill: none;
 stroke: #999;
}
circle {
 fill: none;
 stroke: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-selection.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-path.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-shape.v1.min.js"></script>

<svg width="700" height="110">
  <path></path>
</svg>
```